# Type mismatch. Required: String! Found: Int error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to GET request, but I'm getting error on line 4 in the code below

```
    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
    val url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, null,
        Response.Listener { response ->
            val url = response.getString("url")
        },
        Response.ErrorListener {
            Toast.makeText(this,"something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```

Comment: Check constructor definition and fix it . https://javadoc.io/doc/com.android.volley/volley/1.1.1/com/android/volley/toolbox/JsonObjectRequest.html

Comment: You are sending null instead of url in line 4.
Replace null with url variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havent passed url to request.

```
val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
val url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url, null, //You need to pass url here
    Response.Listener { response ->
        val url = response.getString("url")
    },
    Response.ErrorListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    })
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
```